# Using pointers to access 2D array linearly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to use pointers to treat a 2D array as a 1D array (since that's the way it is in memory to my understanding). I thought I had it, then I figured out that I was only adding to the ASCII value of 'a' (and printing abcdefghijkl instead of abcghidefjkl).

How can I rewrite my printf statement to print abcghidefjkl?
Also, how can I do that with ints and doubles (ie - using data2 and data3)

```
int main()
{

int i = 0;
char data[4][3] = { {'a','b','c'},{'g','h','i'},{'d','e','f'},{'j','k','l'}};
int data2[4][3] = { {1,2,3},{7,8,9},{4,5,6},{10,11,12}};
double data3[4][3] = { {1,2,3},{7,8,9},{4,5,6},{10,11,12}};

for(i=0;i<12;i++)
{
printf("%c\n", **(data)+i*sizeof(char));
}

return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried *(base+i*3+j) ?  i for line and j for column. Maybe *(base+i*3*sizeof(type)+j*sizeof(type))

Comment: No. I'm trying to avoid the use of 'j' and use pointers to treat it like a 1D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change one line of you code

```
#include "stdio.h"

    int main()
    {

    int i = 0;
    char data[4][3] = { {'a','b','c'},{'g','h','i'},{'d','e','f'},{'j','k','l'}};
    int data2[4][3] = { {1,2,3},{7,8,9},{4,5,6},{10,11,12}};
    double data3[4][3] = { {1,2,3},{7,8,9},{4,5,6},{10,11,12}};

    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
    printf("%c\n", *(*data +i));   // here is the change
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So is the sizeof(char) unnecessary? Because when I try to use data2 or data3 and sizeof(int)/sizeof(double) accordingly, it spits out garbage. If I remove sizeof(), it works as expected for all types.

Comment: Yes, the compiler will take care of that, For the case of sizeof(char) it is `1` . therefore doesnot matter.

Comment: That makes sense!

So as an extension, how could I pass data2 to another function (let's call it doStuff()), and put the printf loop there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following array resides within the single block of memory indeed:

```
char data[4][3] = { {'a','b','c'},{'g','h','i'},{'d','e','f'},{'j','k','l'}};
```

thus you are able to treat it whatever manner you like, as long as you are trying to access elements that are within the range of this array still. Simple pointer arithmetic like this would do:

```
int i;
char* ptr = &data[0][0];
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    printf("%c ", *(ptr + i));
```

yet this would output `a b c g h i d e f j k l`. To make it `a b c d e f g h i  j k l` you will probably have to come with something more sophisticated, for example:

```
int i,j;
char* ptr = &data[0][0];
// a b c d e f:
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        printf("%c ", *(ptr + i*6 + j));
// g h i j k l:
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        printf("%c ", *(ptr + i*6 + j + 3));
```

note that it is guaranteed by the standard that `sizeof(char)` will always return `1`, thus it can be omitted. In case of an array of `int`s, the code would need only 2 changes: `ptr` would have to be declared as `int*` and `printf` should use `%d` specifier. You still wouldn't have to use `sizeof`.